# How to draw the imagebutton and place it in the lower left corner

Tags: java, libgdx

I have the button:

```
soundBtnStyle = new ImageButton.ImageButtonStyle();
    soundBtnStyle.up = skinBac.getDrawable("on");//
    soundBtnStyle.down = skinBac.getDrawable("off"); //

    soundsButton = new ImageButton(soundBtnStyle);
    soundsButton.setSize(120, 120);

    soundsButton.addListener(new ClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
            game.rainMusic.setVolume(0.0f);
        }
    });
```

call the button in the constructor,I can not figure out how to add a button to the stage.

```
game.batch.begin();
    game.batch.draw(soundsButton, 0, 0,120, 120);
game.batch.end();
enter code here
```

It does not work, an error
[image]

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: @ SurvivalMachine
update question

Answer (score 1):

If only there was a magical place where you could look up things like this.

https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/ui/ImageButton.html#draw-com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Batch-float-

I wonder if that button classes draw routine could help. Hmmmmmm.

Answer (score 0):

Right after you create a new ImageButton you can add it like:

`soundsButton = new ImageButton(soundBtnStyle);
 soundsButton.setSize(120, 120);
//add button here
stage.addActor(soundsButton);
//set position at x=0 & y=0 as
soundButton.setPosition(0,0);`

Answer (score 0):

The `draw()` method [only accepts](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/Batch.html) `Texture` and `TextureRegion`. You're passing an `ImageButton`. `ImageButton` is an `Actor` and is part of Scene2d and they are usually used along with `Screen`, `Game` and `Stage`. [You should check this tutorial](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Scene2d) to know more about Scene2D.